# why is using .then() 3x faster then await in my test?

Tags: javascript

This could totally be me misunderstanding something about the way async/await works in Javascript, but I haven't figured it out yet.

I have a simple test that uses some helpers to generate mock data before actually running the test.

Here's the helper function:

```
async create(numCustomers, businessId, options) {

    options = _.assign({ type: 'customer' }, options);

    const customers = await Factory.createMany('user', options, numCustomers);

    return Promise.all(customers.map(async (c) => {
        await AccountHelper.create(businessId, c.get('id'));
        return c;
    }));
}
```

and here's two versions of the test:

`async/await` version:

```
const customers = await CustomerHelper.create(10, Constants.fakeBusinessId);

await Promise.all(customers.map(async (c) => {
    await PetHelper.create(1, c.get('id'));
}));

const res = await server.inject(request);
expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
```

.then() version:

```
CustomerHelper.create(10, Constants.fakeBusinessId).then(async (customers) => {

    await Promise.all(customers.map(async (c) => {
        await PetHelper.create(1, c.get('id'));
    }));

    const res = await server.inject(request);
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});
```

The `.then()` version finishes in about 2 seconds, where the `async/await` version finishes in almost 7 seconds. Changing between these two forms seems to be the only variable.

I'm running Node 8.9.4 on OSX.

I appreciate any insights or education :)

Comment: It could be that one form is running in parallel, the other is sequential.

Comment: Your await version has to create all the customers before running the test, whereas your then method runs on each one as soon as they return, so it's more parallel.

Comment: @Turksarama - that implies that the `.then` is called more than once

Comment: Nope, then calls _the function you pass into it_ once for each customer.

Comment: so, `(async (customers) => {` is called more than once?

Comment: Well, a function call is something of a simplification as what's actually happening is there's a pipeline being set up with customers as a generator.  It's more like Javascript (or rather, your Javascript engine) can see you're passing in something which can generate values, and then calling a function which maps across those values so it can optimise them under the hood into one longer function operating on the values rather than the generator itself.

Comment: huh? generator? where? I see no `function*` - did you just make that up?

Comment: I think he means "producer", as in generic producer/consumer pipelines.

Comment: I think @Turksarama may be right. There is some sort of crypto error warning that occurs when I create a user in this test and it happens to pop up 10 times when using the async/await version. With the .then() version, it only pops up once....hmmm

Comment: I still don't understand why that is, but I guess my question is: is there a completely analagous version of async/await that has the same/better performance?

Comment: I suspect your `then` version is finishing the test before execution is complete. try returning the promise or calling the test `done` callback with another chained `then`.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner i admittedly forgot to call done() or return the promise with the `then` version. If I call `done()` it's still way faster and I see 1 of those crypto warnings I mentioned above. However, if I return the promise, it takes longer and I see 10 of those messages. The interesting thing is that regardless of which way it's done, the assertion always passes. I left this out, but I also check the result to make sure the proper number of pets are returned (`expect(result).to.have.length(10);`). That said, I wouldn't expect the test to pass if it was returning too early. thoughts?

Comment: When you are calling `done()` make sure you either pass it as the argument to a then, (without calling it) or call it in a callback to a `then`. It's tricky to tell when you are making synchronous calls and when you are making synchronous. Remember that when you make a function call to an async function without await, the next line executes nearly immediately (which is why callbacks and `await` s are needed).

Comment: Additionally, many test frameworks pass if there are no errors, and no assertions/expectations mean no errors. So if the test ends before you even get to your assertions, well, that erroneously counts as a pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods should be roughly the same duration, *as long as you are properly signaling your test framework that the test is done*. (Either by returning a promise or calling the `done` callback, in most test frameworks)

If you do not signal the framework properly, then the test will exit before the async processing is finished (or even started, in many cases). Also, if your assertions / expectations wait for an asynchronous event, then they will not even be made, and a test with no assertions is (in most frameworks) a passing test. Because of this, `async`/`await` is becoming the preferred style for tests, because it is harder (though not impossible) to incorrectly signal the test framework (as your example illustrates).

Proper ways to signal a test framework the test is done (for mocha/jest style frameworks):

```
it('does async work with await', async function (){
  let result = await asyncWork()
  assertItWorked(result)
})

it('does async work with returned promise', function (){
  return asyncWork().then(function (result) {
    assertItWorked(result)
  })
})

it('does async work with promise and callback', function (done){
  asyncWork().then(function (result) {
    assertItWorked(result)
    done() // note that this method will timeout if it fails, instead of displaying the error message, but you still get a failure
  })
})

it('does async work with promise and chained callback', function (done){
  asyncWork().then(function (result) {
    assertItWorked(result)
  }).then(done)
})
```

Improper ways that almost look right:

```
it('does async work but does not wait', function (done){
  asyncWork().then(function (result) {
    assertItWorked(result)
  })
  done() // this gets called before async work is done, and no assertions are made
})

it('does async work with promise and chained callback, but calls callback too soon', function (done){
  asyncWork().then(function (result) {
    assertItWorked(result)
  }).then(done()) // this is effectively identical to the previous example, because done gets called immediately
})
```

also note that the `async`/`await` style fully catches thrown errors/rejections from `asyncWork`, although with more code the other styles could as well.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. It looked like everything was working, but I was getting a false positive and I wasn't returning the promise. Thanks for clearing this up!